# Where to upload the odd and rare emulators and related to them ROMs & software?

Tags: emulation, archival

Over time, I collected some rare and interesting emulators and their roms and software for, for example, region specific computer machines, rare 1-2 gen consoles and what not. Many of these emulators are no longer possible to find online (at least in 15 minutes). I wonder, if there an appropriate place to upload, for them to still be available to the public, and perhaps for them to be preserved?

Answer (score 14):

You could upload them [to the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/create), which already hosts large quantities of emulators and [software](https://archive.org/details/softwarelibrary) (much of which is now available in in-browser emulators).

Once you’ve finished uploading your archives, ping [Jason Scott](http://ascii.textfiles.com/) for help getting them categorised appropriately. Or even, if you’re planning on uploading lots of software, ping him before you get started, he’ll set you up with better tools for large quantities of uploads (thanks to [Jim Nelson](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4222/jim-nelson) for the reminder!).

Comment: If the original poster has a large amount of software, I recommend pinging Jason Scott first for assistance in organizing the work.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the Internet Archive, there’s also a “New Dumps” thread for ROM dumps on the MAME forums:

https://forums.bannister.org/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=80278#Post80278